# Format of kitti poses dataset poses and how re-create using imu

Tags: computer-vision, imu

I am currently trying to make a  monocular visual odometry system for a project.
autonomus rc car.
I read these blogs-
https://avisingh599.github.io/vision/visual-odometry-full/
https://avisingh599.github.io/vision/monocular-vo/
 and downloaded this github code-
https://github.com/snmnmin12/VisualOdometry
I modified the code to use a webcam.
I wanted to use the concepts described above mentioned  websites for my application and use images form a logitech webcam.
So I downloaded the kitti dataset gray and also the poses dataset.
But I don't understand the meaning or nature of the poses data.
So I googled and found these results-
https://github.com/MichaelGrupp/evo/wiki/Formats 
https://github.com/alexkreimer/odometry/blob/master/devkit/readme.txt
 These information helped me to understand in which format the text file used in the code.
But I still dont understand what does it contain and how can I make my own dataset using  sensors like imu or wheel encoders.
Or how to generate poses information so that I can use it for my own purpose.

The dataset - 
http://www.cvlibs.net/download.php?file=data_odometry_gray.zip
The data I dont understand and want recreate-
  http://www.cvlibs.net/download.php?file=data_odometry_poses.zip